# Cookies not being set immediately in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using djangorestauth for the backend and the token it returns back is not saved in the cookies from universal cookies immediately. I have this handle login:

```
const handleLogin = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
setIsClicked(true);

const csrftoken = getCookie("csrf");
const url = "http://localhost:8000/rest-auth/login/";

const cookies = new Cookies();
fetch(url, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json",
    "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    username: username,
    password: password,
  }),
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((key) => setToken(key.key));
cookies.set("token", token);
};
```

and a useEffect() to test

```
useEffect(() => {
if (isClicked) {
  const cookies = new Cookies();
  console.log("THE TOKEN COOKIE: ", cookies.get("token"));
  setIsClicked(false);
}
}, [isClicked]);
```

The problem: When I click the Login button, the token returned was obviously not set immediately because it returns undefined or blank at the first click. And when I input the wrong username and password, the token is still being output

Answer (score 0):

```
const handleLogin = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();


const csrftoken = getCookie("csrf");
const url = "http://localhost:8000/rest-auth/login/";

const cookies = new Cookies();
fetch(url, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json",
    "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    username: username,
    password: password,
  }),
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((key) => {
    setToken(key.key)
    cookies.set("token", key.key);
    setIsClicked(true);
  })
};
```

explanation
you need to await to finish the fetch

NOTE: `setIsClicked` change the name to `isSubmitSuccess`